# Kubernetes doesn't recognise wildcard*

Tags: linux, kubernetes

I am trying to use wildcard on `kubectl cp` command however its failling to recognise wildcard.

```
$ kubectl cp mypod:/tmp/exampleFiles.* /tmp
tar: /tmp/exampleFiles.*: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Although my Kubernetes is up to date (v1.15.2) and according to [this git issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/78854) wildcard problem is fixed, but I am confused that why its not working for me. Is my syntax wrong? what do you think the problem is? please help!

Answer (score 1):

For everyone's benefit, I am pasting working code as suggested by **heyjared** user on https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/78854

```
Use find with xargs as a workaround:

find . | xargs -i{} kubectl cp {} namespace/pod:path
```

It worked for me. I replaced "." with my needed source path.

**Example:**

```
find <source_path> | xargs -i{} kubectl cp {} namespace/pod:<path_inside_pod>
```

Like:

```
find /var/tmp/data/ | xargs -i{} kubectl cp {} namespace/pod:/tmp/
```

This will copy all contents inside local /var/tmp/data/ directory and store it under /tmp/ inside pod.

Comment: does it work if you find path in pod?

Comment: Yes, it will work

Answer (score 0):

From what I have researched this has not worked in any version of `kubectl` since wild card support was added.

`kubectl cp --help` has no examples or mentions about supporting wildcards either.

There are some [examples](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/68222#issuecomment-500402673) showing the same problem past 1.14.0 when this was supposed be fixed/added.

Basing on all the info above Kubernetes does not support wildcards.